# Why does a Try work here when the parameter does not expect a Try?

Tags: scala

I'm reading [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 8: Welcome to the Future](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) and one part of code I'm confused about is this:

```
import scala.util.Try

object CoffeeSync extends App {

  // Some type aliases, just for getting more meaningful method signatures:
  type CoffeeBeans = String
  type GroundCoffee = String
  case class Water(temperature: Int)
  type Milk = String
  type FrothedMilk = String
  type Espresso = String
  type Cappuccino = String

  // dummy implementations of the individual steps:
  def grind(beans: CoffeeBeans): GroundCoffee = s"ground coffee of $beans"
  def heatWater(water: Water): Water = water.copy(temperature = 85)
  def frothMilk(milk: Milk): FrothedMilk = s"frothed $milk"
  def brew(coffee: GroundCoffee, heatedWater: Water): Espresso = "espresso"
  def combine(espresso: Espresso, frothedMilk: FrothedMilk): Cappuccino = "cappuccino"

  // going through these steps sequentially:
  def prepareCappuccino(): Try[Cappuccino] = for {
    ground <- Try(grind("arabica beans"))
    water <- Try(heatWater(Water(25)))
    espresso <- Try(brew(ground, water))
    foam <- Try(frothMilk("milk"))
  } yield {
    combine(espresso, foam)
  }
```

All of this works fine, but what I'm confused about is why `Try` works in the For Fomprehension?

`grind("arabica beans")` is supposed to return a value of type `GroundCoffee` which is a type alias for `String`.   I get that For Comprehensions are iterating through a Collection and that this gets assigned to one value, and that `Try(grind(...))` is viewed as a Collection of 1 element so that `ground` represents the element "unwrapped".

But if that explanation were complete, then I wouldn't get a compile error when I do the following:

```
// going through these steps sequentially:
  def prepareCappuccino(): Try[Cappuccino] = for {
    // Replaced Try with Seq
    ground <- Seq(grind("arabica beans"))
    water <- Try(heatWater(Water(25)))
    espresso <- Try(brew(ground, water))
    foam <- Try(frothMilk("milk"))
  } yield {
    combine(espresso, foam)
  }
```

This gives me the following:

```
    <console>:41: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.util.Try[CoffeeSync.Cappuccino]
    (which expands to)  scala.util.Try[String]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
           water <- Try(heatWater(Water(25)))
                 ^
<console>:40: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Nothing]
 required: scala.util.Try[CoffeeSync.Cappuccino]
    (which expands to)  scala.util.Try[String]
           ground <- Seq(grind("arabica beans"))
                  ^
```

So I guess what I'm really asking is **Why does my `Seq[GroundCoffee]` get converted into a `Seq[Nothing]`?**  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get that For Comprehensions are iterating through a Collection

This is not the complete truth. For comprehensions can be used with every type that has methods `map`, `flatmap`, `foreach`, `filter` or `withFilter`. And every `for` block is implicitly converted into chain of these methods calls according to [rules](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops). For example:

```
for (p1 <-e1; p2 <-e2) yield (p1, p2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
e1.flatMap(p1 => e2.map(p2 => (p1, p2)))
```

In your case (I simplified it a bit, this is enough to get compile error, no matter what you actually return):

```
  def prepareCappuccino() = for {
    ground <- Seq(grind("arabica beans"))
    water <- Try(heatWater(Water(25)))
  } yield water
```

your code will be translated to:

```
  def prepareCappuccino() = 
    Seq(grind("arabica beans"))
    .flatMap(ground => Try(heatWater(Water(25))).map(water => water))
```

And here you got a problem: method `flatMap` in `Seq` has signature:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

It takes `f` - a function of type `A => GenTraversableOnce[B]`. But actually you passed there a function of type `A => Try[B]` and since `Try[B]` is not a subtype of `GenTraversableOnce[B]` you got compile error.

So you just can't combine `Try` and `Seq` or other collection in the same for block in this way unless you have some implicit conversion from `Try` to `GenTraversableOnce`. For example you can combine `Option` and collections:

```
val r = for {
  x <- Seq(3)
  y <- Option(5)
} yield (x,y)
```

This code compiles successfully because there is an implicit conversion defined in `Option` object:

```
  implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList
```

Comment: There's also a `toOption` method on the `Try` that you can use to make this work. There are reasons for which `Try` is not actually a Monad which prevents the composition you are after at design level. Details here: https://gist.github.com/ms-tg/6222775.

Comment: @ka4eli, thanks for your thorough answer!  Exactly answers my question.  I guess it's best to always be thinking that a for comprehension is really just syntactic sugar for `map`'s and `flatMap`'s.